# Count vowels in a string with ruby

Tags: ruby, iteration

My objective is to return the number of vowels in a given string. I've tried this code:

```
def count_vowels(string)
  vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
  chars_ary = string.split(//)
  ary_with_vowels = chars_ary.take_while {|letter| vowels.include?(letter)}
  return ary_with_vowels.length
end
```

and it doesn't pass the majority of test cases. I understand that there are multiple other ways to solve this problem, but I want to solve it using the code that I provided.

Can someone give me some insight as to why this isn't working?

Comment: for which test case it didn't work?

Comment: It was failing the test cases where the string didn't begin with an 'a' and only had 'a' as its vowel because the iteration breaks out once a condition returns false. @meagar explained it best, I was using the wrong method.

Comment: You also aren't handling strings with uppercase vowels. You ought to do `chars_ary = string.downcase.split(//)`

Comment: Are you aware of [`String#count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html#method-i-count)? i.e. `string.count('aeiou')`

Comment: I suppose you could write `string.scan(/[aeiou]/i).size`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`take_while` is the wrong method here. It starts at the beginning, and "takes" elements as long as the block returns a truthy value. It stops the first time you encounter a letter that isn't a vowel.

You want `select` which selects all the elements for which the block returns a truthy value.

Comment: That is absolutely correct! I went back to the documentation to read take_whiles implementation and it was exactly how you described, I read it way too fast. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

This way is easier:

```
 def count_vowels(string)
   string.count('aeiou')
 end
```

Comment: I would throw a `.downcase` in there (or add "AEIOU" to the count string), but this is the best solution to the general problem.

Comment: Since the OP was also not looking for upper case vowels, I kept it that way. Going that far, one would also think about whether, for instance, ü or æ or η or あ or ø should also be considered a vowel. I'm not a linguist and don't know, how exactly the concept of vowels is mapped to the whole Unicode character set, so I better leave this decision to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Let's benchmark a few approaches.

```
require 'fruity'
require 'set'

SET_OF_VOWELS = %w| a e i o u |.to_set

def string_count(str)
  str.count('aeiou')
end

def set_include?(str)
  str.each_char.count { |c| SET_OF_VOWELS.include?(c) }
end

def use_hash(str)
  h = str.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
  SET_OF_VOWELS.sum { |c| h[c] }
end

alpha = ('a'..'z').to_a

[1_000, 10_000, 100_000, 1_000_000].each do |n|

  puts "\nString length = #{n}"     
  str = Array.new(n) { alpha.sample }.join

  compare(
    string_count: -> { string_count(str) },
    set_include?: -> { set_include?(str) },
    use_hash:     -> { use_hash(str) }
  )
end
```

The results are as follows.

```
String length = 1000
Running each test 1024 times. Test will take about 9 seconds.
string_count is faster than set_include? by 159x ± 1.0
set_include? is faster than use_hash by 37.999999999999986% ± 1.0%

String length = 10000
Running each test 128 times. Test will take about 11 seconds.
string_count is faster than set_include? by 234x ± 1.0
set_include? is faster than use_hash by 35.00000000000001% ± 1.0%

String length = 100000
Running each test 16 times. Test will take about 14 seconds.
string_count is faster than set_include? by 246x ± 1.0
set_include? is faster than use_hash by 35.00000000000001% ± 1.0%

String length = 1000000
Running each test 2 times. Test will take about 18 seconds.
string_count is faster than set_include? by 247x ± 1.0
set_include? is faster than use_hash by 34.00000000000001% ± 1.0%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, its looking at each character in the vowels array and comparing it to each character in the string and the p it if the condition is true.

```
def vowles(string)
arr = []
vowels = %w(a e i o u)
vowels.each do |x|
    if string.each_char { |letter| (arr << x) if x == letter }
    end
  end
  p "#{arr} has #{arr.count} vowels"
end
vowles("wwwweeeeeee")
```

or the more efficient

```
def vowels(string)
  p string.scan(/[a e i o u]/).count
end
vowels("hello world")
```